# Get the list of files in a directory in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

This is the script that I have written, only "FOR LOOP" is not working -
**Getting this error - Please suggest me how to proceed further.

/var/folders/g9/bgcqz8jn4b7gm47k95f15lvm0000gp/T/jenkins5094260696780533763.sh: line 21: ${~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/}*: bad substitution
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure**

```
#!/bin/bash

. ~/.profile
xcode9

security find-identity -p codesigning -v

#ls '/Users/airwatch/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/'

ls ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/

output=$(ls ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/ | wc -l)
echo "Total provisioning profiles :" $output

#cat ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/Accenture_Fit_Distribution.mobileprovision


for entry in "${~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/}*"
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

Comment: What do you expect from `${<path>}` todo? The syntax expects a variable name not a path

Comment: Requiring a script to source your `.profile` is generally a bad practice. There doesn't seem to be anything in this script which depends on anything from your profile anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As jeb already explained in his comment, if your write `${...something...}` in bash, the *...something...* must be a variable name, optionally followed by some parameter substitution (as explained in the section *PARAMETERS* in the bash man page. In your case, what is written between `${` and `}` is not a variable name, hence the error.

You probably want something like

```
for entry in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me -

for entry in "$(ls ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/)"
do
  echo "$entry"
done

Comment: Here, you use `$(ls ....)` instead of `${....}`, as written in your post. This would however produce funny results if `Provisioning Profiles` contained files where the names contain spaces or newlines. In general, the safe (and simplest way) is the one I outlined in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to change it to something like:

```
...


dir=~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
for entry in "$dir"/*
do
  echo "$entry"
done

[Update: Fixed error with comments from user1934428]
```

Comment: This would not work. The ~ would not expand to the home directory when used in this way (due to quoting). Also, the spaces around the `=` sign are incorrect. Your solution would work if written as `dir=~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`?

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, true: I tried locally with another folder and before posting here I copy/pasted the line from the original post and messed up the answer. Thanks!